# Send PHP particular variable to angualrjs controller

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have a PHP page with three echo statement. I want to get the particular `$result` variable in angularjs on success. I am using alert(data) to alert all the echo statement. How do I get the particular PHP variable in angularjs.

PHP:

```
      function add($value1,$value2) 
      { 
               $result =$value1 + $value2; 
                echo("The sum of $value1 and $value2 is $result "); 
                echo("$value1 + $value2 = $result"); 
                echo("$result");
                exit; 
       }
```

3 echo statements. I want the `$result` variable send to angularjs.

app.js :

```
            $scope.cal=function(){

   $scope.opers = $scope.oper ;
      $http({      
                    method: "POST",
                   url: "oper.php",
                 
                  data:{ 'value': $scope.value1,
                          'valu': $scope.value2,
                          'opers': $scope.oper,
                          } ,
             headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
      })   

      .success(function(data) {
       
        console.log(data);
        alert(data);
        $scope.result = data ;

    } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple but functional:

IN PHP: create a variable, example

```
$manualjson ="[{"value1":"'.$value1.'","value2":"'.$value2.'","value3":"'.$value3.'"}]";
echo $manualjson;
```

then in app.js

```
var text = (returned $manualjson) --get your echo into a var

obj = JSON.parse(text);
var value1= obj[0].value1;
var value2= obj[0].value2;
var value3= obj[0].value3;
```

A little bit rude but functional